# Get 1 element from each javascript array concat then loop into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have 4 arrays, I'd like to combine them into 1. I can do that, but I'd like to take one element from each array, push it to my new array, then get the next 4 and so on. This is what I got:

```
var a = [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "bam", "bun", "fun" ];
var b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var c=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var d=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
var neat=[];
neat= a.concat(b, c,d);
//neat=["foo","bar","baz","bam","bun","fun",1,2,3,4,5,6,"a","b","c","d","e","f",7,8,9,10,11, 12]
```

The result I want would be something like this:

```
//neat=["foo",1,"a",7,"bar",2,"b",8...]
```

I'm not sure if a loop will work or if I need to use another function

Comment: Is it always 4 arrays? Are the lengths always the same? These are the kinds of questions that need to be answered before finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code :

```js
var a = [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "bam", "bun", "fun" ];
var b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var c=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var d=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
var neat=[];
//neat= a.concat(b, c,d);
//neat=["foo","bar","baz","b



for (var i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) 
{
neat.push(a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]);
}
console.log(neat);
```

Comment: Do you believe that your solution is better than Justin's ?

Comment: With respect to the Time complexity, both of them run in O(n).

Comment: @Taurus "better" is very subjective. `for` loop is generally the fastest, and works in all browsers (arrow functions are not supported in Internet Explorer)

Comment: @Slai Let's replace "better" with "more efficient". But, it seems cleaner to me to do it using a built-in function (rather than a `for` loop).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each source array is the same length:

```
a.forEach((e, i) => {
  neat.push(e, b[i], c[i], d[i]);
};
```

Comment: they are the same length for my case

Answer (score 1):

While Justins answer is correct, however if the lengths of the array are not the same every time, you could do

```
var maxItems = Math.max(a.length,b.length,c.length,d.length);

var neat = [];

for(var i = 0; i < maxItems; i++){

  if(a[i] != undefined){
    neat.push(a[i]);
  }

  if(b[i] != undefined){
    neat.push(b[i]);
  }

  if(c[i] != undefined){
    neat.push(c[i]);
  }

  if(d[i] != undefined){
    neat.push(d[i]);
  }
}
```

`Math.max` would find the biggest number of entries from between the 4 arrays, then a simple `for loop` on that number and check if the value is `undefined`before pushing it to `neat array`.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t37zg4y7/1/)

Comment: You should actually use `a.length >= i`, because `a[i] != undefined` will return `false` for both `null` and `undefined` indices. Also, decrementing `1` from `maxItems` in the loop condition is unnecessary and will omit the last item of the largest array.

Comment: @Taurus Well, you don't want `null` and `undefined` values most likely given the data sets are `integers` and `strings`. Indexes in arrays start with `0`, taking 1 away is needed or else you'll end up doing the last iteration on out of index values a.k.a `undefined` values as `Math.max` will return the number of items within the array. Say there are 6 items, `maxItems = 6`, the max index within an array is 5, so last iteration is redundant.

Comment: Yes, but you are saying `i < maxItems - 1`, so, you are actually saying `i < 5`, so the index `5` will not be iterated through.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed what I've done, newbie mistake. Apologies and thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Because the length of the all arrays are equal. So we can easily do that using loop.

```
var a = [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "bam", "bun", "fun" ];
var b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var c=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var d=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
var neat=[], i;

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    neat.push(a[i]);
    neat.push(b[i]);
    neat.push(c[i]);
    neat.push(d[i]);
}
console.log(neat);
```

Comment: You know you can add a series of items using just one `.push`? See other answers below which are the same as yours and show this functionality.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is the same as the other answers here.